# Expanding data frame with "mirror" observations

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame arranged as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(name1=  c("A","A","B"), 
                 name2    =  c("B", "C","C"),
                 size     =  c(10,20,30)),.Names=c("name1","name2","size"), 
            row.names     =  c("1", "2", "3"), class =("data.frame"))
```

I would like to add "mirror" observations as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(name1 =  c("A","B","A", "C", "B", "C"), 
                 name2     =  c("B", "A","C", "A", "C", "B"),
                 size      =  c(10,10,20,20,30,30)),.Names=c("name1","name2","size"), 
                 row.names =  c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class =("data.frame"))
```

Inputs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in two steps,

```
df1 <- df[rep(rownames(df), each = 2),]
df1[c(FALSE, TRUE), 1:2] <- df1[c(FALSE, TRUE), 2:1]

df1
#    name1 name2 size
#1       A     B   10
#1.1     B     A   10
#2       A     C   20
#2.1     C     A   20
#3       B     C   30
#3.1     C     B   30
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df, df[c(2:1, 3)]))
```